# Setting parameter in MapReduce Job configuration

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

Is there any way to set a parameter in job configuration from `Mapper` and is accessible from `Reducer`.

I tried the below code

In Mapper:  `map(..)`    : `context.getConfiguration().set("Sum","100");`
In reducer: `reduce(..)` : `context.getConfiguration().get("Sum");`

But in reducer value is returned as `null`.

Is there any way to implement this or any thing missed out from my side?

Comment: If possible write it to a local file and read it in configure() or setup() of reducer. It should be trivial.

Comment: May I know what's the difference between configure() and setup()? I know configure() will be called once in the mapper class so I can initialze some global variables inside. How about setup()? Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, this is not possible. The job configuration is serialized to XML at run-time by the jobtracker, and is copied out to all task nodes. Any changes to the Configuration object will only affect that object, which is local to the specific task JVM; it will not change the XML at every node.

In general, you should try to avoid any "global" state. It is against the MapReduce paradigm and will generally prevent parallelism. If you absolutely must pass information between the Map and Reduce phase, and you cannot do it via the usual Shuffle/Sort step, then you could try writing to the Distributed Cache, or directly to HDFS.

Comment: Thanks Joe for the info. I tried the second way, write the o/p to HDFS from a reducer and next mapper read the data from HDFS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the new API your code should ideally work. Have you created this "Sum" property at the start of the job creation? For example like this

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.set("Sum", "0");
Job job = new Job(conf);
```

If not you better use

```
context.getConfiguration().setIfUnset("Sum","100");
```

In your mapper class to fix the issue. This is the only thing I can see.

Comment: After setting we can retrieve those values back using context.getConfiguration().get("Sum")