# Pass multiple values back from Hadoop Tools

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Within a Hadoop  Java application, I need to pass multiple integer values back to the caller from MapReduce Tool instances.  So far, I have tried and failed as follows:

- `Tool.run()` returns a single integer value to its caller.
- `Configuration.set()` and `.get()` are handy but as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13228922/setting-parameter-in-mapreduce-job-configuration), *the job configuration is serialized to XML at run-time by the jobtracker, and is copied out to all task nodes. Any changes to the Configuration object will only affect that object, which is local to the specific task JVM; it will not change the XML at every node.*
- `Configuration.getCounter().set()` only works if the caller themselves extends `Configured` and `getConf()` is called, which is not possible form static methods
- I believe that the distributed cache is read-only (hence I haven't actually tried to use it, maybe I should?)

Any idea how I can or should do that?

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by writing an abstract Tool wrapper, with a Job attribute and a protected setter and a public getter for it.